# Connecting with facebook to get user profile link (2020)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In a website, is it possible to ask the user to "connect to facebook" and grant the website access to the profile link - or some other piece of data that can turn into the profile link?

If yes, what API/method should I look at?

By profile link I mean `http://facebook.com/{myprofile}` which links to the person's facebook page.

I see a LOT of posts about this, but they are old and outdated and what you can and cannot do with facebook has changed a lot in the last couple of years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the "real" profile link (including the username) anymore. You can get a link with the API, but it may not be what you want:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

```
/me?fields=link
```

> A link to the person's Timeline. The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.

Edit: Oh, i have answered that question before: [Get "real" profile URL from Facebook Graph API /user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152500/get-real-profile-url-from-facebook-graph-api-user)

Comment: Thanks! So on a website, the only way to get people to link to their own facebook page (`http://facebook.com/{myprofile}`) is to directly ask them to copy/paste that link?

Comment: yes, exactly. but they could just enter any link and there is no way to proof that it is their own.